# Solution set of a linear system with three equations and three unknowns with at least two distinct solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, propositional-calculus, plane-geometry

Proposition:

> If $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ are two distinct solutions
>   of a linear system with three equations and three unknowns then
>   $t(x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0, z_1-z_0)$ is also a solution of that same system
>   for any real number $t$.

I am uncertain on how I might go about determining the truth of this statement. It seems conceiveable, however, I can really only visualise this scenario for a line, rather than a plane. Things higher than $\mathbb{R}^2$ are rather difficult (or impossible) to conceive. It seems like subtracting these points gives a slop of some sort, and then $t$ could be considered the variable for the slope of some linear solution.

Insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to prove in not geometric but in algebraic way.

If you are familiar with matrices then express equations in matrix form and try to express $A \space t(x_1-x_0)$ in terms of $A \space x_1$ and $A \space x_0$. Then you will be able to easily prove the statement.

Comment: I have an inkling on what you might mean, but all I can really come to is the solution set perhaps being $\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]$
$\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{array}\right]=$
$t \left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1-x_0 \\
y_1-y_0 \\
z_1-z_0 \\
\end{array}\right]$

But, it doesn't really seem I've justified or disputed the claim.

Comment: Actually 3 linear equations with 3 variables are equivalent to $Ax=b$ where A is 3*3 matrix, b is 3*1 vector and x is vector of 3 desired variables (x,y,z) (There is small mis-notation here but hope you understand). If you know that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions, i.e. $A x_0=b$ and $A x_1=b$ then what about $A \space t(x_1-x_0)$ ? Can you express it in terms of  $A x_0$ and  $A x_1$?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not complete. It should mention homogenous equation somewhere.
Lets think of the problem in Matrix notation.
$$Ax = b$$
Where $A$ is a $3$ x $3$ Matrix and $b$ the solution vector. If $x^{(1)}=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $x^{(0)}=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ are solutions to your system, then lets define $u=t(x^{(1)}-x^{(0)})$. Plug this into the equation to get
$$Au=A[t(x^{(1)}-x^{(0)})]=tAx^{(1)}-tAx^{(0)}$$
As $x^{(1)}$ and $x^{(0)}$ are solutions to the matrix equation $Ax^{(1)}=b$ and $Ax^{(0)}=b$. From 
$$Au=A[t(x^{(1)}-x^{(0)})]=tAx^{(1)}-tAx^{(0)}=t(b-b)=0$$
we conclude that $u$ is a solution to the homogenous equation.